# Execute MSBuild from C++

Tags: c++, .net, msbuild

It seems very simple to do that from .NET - such as this question: [Running MSBuild at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080300/running-msbuild-at-runtime).

But my program is C++.
I want to find the easiest way of doing this trans world connection easily.

Calling .Net from C++ has never been my thing before.

Comment: [MSBuild on the command line - C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/msbuild-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170). Is this help?

Comment: How would that help the program? Isn't CLI humanoid? Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The question that you link to, [Running MSBuild at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080300/running-msbuild-at-runtime), is C# code using the `ProcessStartInfo` class. But you don't need to "call .Net from C++"; you can use the Win32 API directly. Essentially `ProcessStartInfo` is wrapping [`CreateProcessW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). See "[Creating Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes)" for an overview.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I am going to try for sure. Are you reassuring me that it is possible to launch MsBuild .net process from Win32 with all the parameters that it would require from me?